# Troubleshooting Firebase Emulator

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-tools

I am using Firebase Emulators for Firestore, Cloud Functions and Auth.
When running `firebase emulators:start --only \"functions,auth,firestore\"`, which normally will start those three emulators only, since switching to Node18 (as when building the functions I have been advised to upgrade from Node16 to 18) I have now noticed that the first time I run this command it fails to load the cloud functions with these messages.

```
i  functions: Watching "<project-folder>\functions" for Cloud Functions...
+  functions: Using node@18 from host.
!!  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: 
FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification
```

When building with `firebase deploy --only functions`, this always works perfectly fine.

Any indication as to what is causing this? TIA!

This is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "emulate": "firebase emulators:start --only \"functions,auth,firestore\"",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.4.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```